# How can Explain this method?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, encryption, methods

Can you guys please explain this method? I am trying to implement this code into my program, but the author left no explanation on what it does, or how it does it. please try to keep it understandable.

```
imgl.Image imageKey = imgl.decodeImage(File(imageKeyPath).readAsBytesSync());

for (var i = 0; i < imageKey.length; i++) {
  
   int shift = (i + 1) % imageKey.length;
   int xshift = (i * 255) % imageKey.length;
   imageKey[shift] = imageKey[shift] ^ imageKey[xshift];
 }
```

Comment: What is your goal then? If you don't know what is does, why do you want it in your program?

Comment: It's converting a file to list<int> and then shifting these bytes (maybe an image filter to mirror it)

Comment: I don't know exactly what it does, but I think running the loop backwards, starting with i=imageKey.length-1 and down to and including i=0, will undo it.

Comment: it's work in my program , my program it's( image encryption ) , just i need to understand this code